# How to segment letters and text blobs?

Tags: image-processing

This [new article from Google research](http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2015/07/how-google-translate-squeezes-deep.html) describes how their Translate app preprocesses an image on a phone before applying convnets:

> It needs to weed out background objects like trees or cars, and pick
>   up on the words we want translated. It looks at blobs of pixels that
>   have similar color to each other that are also near other similar
>   blobs of pixels. Those are possibly letters, and if they’re near each
>   other, that makes a continuous line we should read.

[image]

***How can I do this with Mathematica?***

Here is what I have so far:

```
test = Rasterize@
  Overlay[{ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], 
    Style[StringTake[ExampleData[{"Text", "ToBeOrNotToBe"}], 42], 
     RandomColor[], 18]}]

LocalAdaptiveBinarize[test, 40, {0.85, 0.07}]
```

Comment: As you know, it's discouraged to post questions that don't show any effort at writing your own code.

Comment: I know I just found a typos, I just added what I have